# What is the meaning of "all night long"?

Tags: meaning, usage

What is the meaning of "all night long"? I think it means "throughout the whole night" like the dictionary says, but is it really the case? I am asking because it never really means that if you consider the context in which it is used.

For example:

> He started singing **in the middle of the night**, and woke him up and
>   continued to do so **all night long**.

Since he started during the middle of the night, he didn't sing "all night long".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of "all night long" is correct. Whether or not this makes the sentence nonsensical is a matter of debate. Most native English speakers would not quibble over this.

References to "day" and "night" are kind of relative. For example, if you had an "*all-day* meeting" you would not expect it to last from sunrise to sunset. You would expect it to refer to a *working day*. Likewise "all night" would not instantly be taken to mean sunset to sunrise. I think the default understanding of it would be *the hours during which you normally sleep*.

Also, if someone said "I've been vacationing in Florida *all my life*" you would not assume that their entire life had been one long vacation in Florida. The idiomatic use of terms like "all day", "all night" or "all my life" allows for reference to intermittent, repeating occurrences with intervals, breaks, and can be relative to the context.

If you wanted to be fussy, the sentence could have instead said:

> ... and *he* continued to do so *for the rest of the night*.

But while I'm at it, I have a number of other issues with the sentence, out of context. When it says "he continued to do so", does that refer to him continuing to sing, or continuing to wake up the third person? I also feel it should be "*which* woke him up" (not "and").